# What is the best voting system where all voters are omniscient and perfectly logical?

Tags: voting-theory

We can model each voter's preferences by assigning a real number, called a *score*, on the interval $[0, 1]$ to each candidate. The goal of each voter is to elect a candidate with the maximal score according to their own preferences.

Voters are allowed to coordinate and the voting system doesn't need to be deterministic. My intuition tells me approval voting where ties are broken uniformly at random but I'm unsure.

**Edit:** For clarity, all voters vote as tactically as possible. Voters will only compromise if doing so will ensure/increase the probability of a better outcome. Omniscience also applies to knowing how each voter fills out their ballot.

Comment: There are many voting systems.  I believe that there are four common qualities we would like a "fair" voting system to have, but they turn out to be contradictory, so it is always a tradeoff.

Comment: A reasonable question. Look up Arrow’s theorem.

Comment: This question is likely unanswerable. There is no single best voting system, and different people prefer it to have different properties. In addition, it's unclear what omniscient means. If A's vote depends on B's, and vice versa, then omniscience w.r.t. the votes of others quickly leads to contradiction.